# CS50 - LOAD - Get random character from no where when trying to execute load

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, hashtable, cs50

I am new to C programming. I am trying to do the pset5 in CS50 while trying to understand the concepts of memory, linked list and hashtable. I wrote the code and it compiled but there seems to be something wrong because every time I tried to execute the code it returns some garbage value. Could anyone please help me with that? Many thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/small"

typedef struct node
{
char WORD[LENGTH + 1];
struct node *next;
}
node;

int hash(char *word);

int main(void)
{
node **HASHTABLE = malloc(sizeof(node) * 26);

//open the dictionary
FILE *dic = fopen(DICTIONARY, "r");
if (dic == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open the library\n");
    return 1;
}

int index = 0;
char word[LENGTH + 1];

for (int c = fgetc(dic); c != EOF; c = fgetc(dic))
{
    word[index] = c;
    index++;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        int table = hash(word);
        printf("%d\n", table);
        //create a newnode
        node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(newnode->WORD, word);
        newnode->next = NULL;

        printf("Node: %s\n", newnode->WORD);
        index = 0;

        //add new node to hash table
        if (HASHTABLE[table] == NULL)
        {
            HASHTABLE[table] = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            HASHTABLE[table]->next = newnode;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    node *p = HASHTABLE[i];
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", p->WORD);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

//free memory
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    node *p = HASHTABLE[i];
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = temp;
    }
}
free(HASHTABLE);
}


int hash(char *word)
{
int i = 0;
if (islower(word[0]))
    return i = word[0] - 'a';
if (isupper(word[0]))
    return i = word[0] - 'A';
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `for (int c = fgetc(dic); c != EOF; c = fgetc(dic))` is customarily written as `int c; while ((c = fgetc(dic)) != EOF)`

Comment: btw the output you should include as a code block, not as an image...

Comment: Another issue is that try adding 3 words with the same initial letter - your hash table linking is incorrect.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you very much for your comments. They are very helpful! This is my first question so I was struggling to include a code also so sorry for the image. And I do not really get your comment on the 3 words with the same initial letter... I am just trying to run with a trial dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has serious problems that result in undefined behavior.

Two of them are the result of this line:

```
node **HASHTABLE = malloc(sizeof(node) * 26);
```

That allocates 26 `node` **structures**, but the `HASHTABLE` variable expects the address of a pointer to an array of `node *` **pointers** (that's the `**` in the `node **HASHTABLE` declaration).

So, you should replace it with something like:

```
node **HASHTABLE = malloc( 26 * sizeof( *HASHTABLE ) );
```

Note that I used the dereferenced value of the variable being assigned to - `HASHTABLE`.  This means in this case a `node` (one less `*` than in the declaration).  So if the type of `HASHTABLE` changes, you don't need to make any other changes to the `malloc()` statement.

That problem, while technically undefined behavior, likely wouldn't cause any problems.

However, there's still a problem with

```
node **HASHTABLE = malloc( 26 * sizeof( *HASHTABLE ) );
```

that **will** cause problems - and serious ones.

That array of 26 pointers isn't initialized - **you don't know what's in them**.  They can point anywhere.  So this won't work well, if at all:

```
    if (HASHTABLE[table] == NULL)
```

Meaning this points off to somewhere unknown:

```
    HASHTABLE[table]->next = newnode;
```

And **that** will cause all kinds of problems.

The simplest fix?  Initialize the values all to zero by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`:

```
node **HASHTABLE = calloc( 26, sizeof( *HASHTABLE ) );
```

Until that's fixed, any results from your entire program are questionable, at best.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It helps me understand a lot more about those functions!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the garbage is that you didn't *null-terminate* the string:

```
strcpy(newnode->WORD, word);
```

`strcpy` expects the `src` to point to a null-terminated string. Simply adding 0 at the end. Simply terminate it with

```
word[index] = 0;
```

before the `strcpy`.

Other than that, [the ones in Andrew Henle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327725/918959) should be addressed too, but I am not going to repeat them here.

---

BTW, next you will notice that

```
HASHTABLE[table]->next = newnode;
```

wouldn't work properly - that code always inserts the node as the 2nd one. But you want to *always* insert the new node unconditionally as the *head*, with

```
newnode->next = HASHTABLE[table];
HASHTABLE[table] = newnode;
```

There need not be any special condition for inserting the *first* node to a *bucket*.